# Is it possible to persist paho MQTT session state on disk?

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I'm assessing python MQTT clients for use in an environment where data loss could be extremely costly.  As a protocol MQTT supports QOS 2 and we know our message broker handles this well with regard to persisting message queues and session states to disk.

But for the client we're having a little more trouble ensuring messages are provably sent.  While's there's little we could do about a complete loss of client machine (corrupted disk etc.) We do want to make sure that simpler issues (such as restarting the publisher or subscriber process) will not cause data loss.

Looking at [Paho MQTT client](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/) I don't see any obvious way to create a `paho.mqtt.client.Client` such that it can pick up where a previous one left off.

If this is not possible, I'd be interested in any hints around clients that can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The Paho Python client doesn't support message/session persistence for queued high QOS messages, but the [Paho Java](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/java/index.php) client does.

As a side note, I'm sure the Paho project would welcome a pull request to add persistence support to the Python client.